# Collections.sort with Custom Comparator does not actually sort

Tags: java

Collections.sort seems to not sort my ArrayLists even though the Comparator seems to be called properly. It appears that after performing the sort on each Arraylist the sort does not stick, the items in ArrayLists remain in their original order.

This is how I go through each Arraylist and sort them, then I print them to check:

```
public void SortCreatures ( int x ) {
    for ( Party p : SorcerersCave.theCave.parties ) {
        //cycles through parties to sort each ones ArrayList members
        switch ( x ) {
            case 0 :
                Collections.sort( p.members, new compareThings.CEmpathy());
            case 1 :
                Collections.sort( p.members, new compareThings.CFear() );
            case 2 :
                Collections.sort( p.members, new compareThings.CCarry() );
        }
    }
    generateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "Displaying Sorted Creatures:" );
    for ( Party p : SorcerersCave.theCave.parties ) {
        generateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "" + p );
        for ( Creature c : p.members ){
            generateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "\t" + c );
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output when using case 0: (the 5th Int in the 5th column is Empathy):

```
Displaying Sorted Creatures:
10000 - School//Party for refference
20002 - Vampire - Loren - 10000 - 3 - 28 - 59
20003 - Leprechaun - Claretta - 10000 - 48 - 64 - 97
20000 - Witch - Catheryn - 10000 - 5 - 77 - 98
20001 - Kobold - Kim - 10000 - 60 - 42 - 208
10001 - Gaggle//Party for refference
20004 - Elf - Bob - 10001 - 51 - 51 - 155
20006 - Yeti - Soraya - 10001 - 28 - 30 - 209
20007 - Pixie - Dusty - 10001 - 8 - 74 - 242
20005 - Hero - Sol - 10001 - 90 - 24 - 273
10002 - Gang
...
```

This is the Comparator for Empathy: (the 5th Int in the 5th column is Empathy)

```
public static class CEmpathy implements Comparator< Creature > {
    @Override
    public int compare( Creature o1, Creature o2 ) {
        int                             c1 = o1.getEmpathy();
        int                             c2 = o2.getEmpathy();
        System.out.println( c1 + " & " + c2 );
        if ( c1 < c2 ) return -1;
        else if ( c1 == c2 ) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }
}
```

What confuses me is that the Comparator seems to execute properly, this a print out of each pair of numbers being compared.

```
60 & 5
3 & 60
3 & 60
3 & 5
48 & 5
48 & 60
90 & 51//new party
28 & 90
28 & 90
28 & 51
8 & 51
8 & 28
...
```

I have been at this for 2 hours printing at every step but everything seems to be executing properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to `break` at the end of your `case`s, and switch cases are fall through.

Comment: Side comment: all your if/else logic could be written as: `return Integer.compare(c1, c2);`

Comment: @jlordo Post an answer?

Comment: To avoid the usage of the switch, you could have a `Map<Integer, Comparator< Creature >>` and have each index mapped with the corresponding comparator.

Comment: @assylias Or even as `return c2-c1;` - which yields a different result but with the same effect.

Comment: Turned out it was the fact I did not break out of my Case, should I delete this question or change the question to something more relevant such as Collections.sort does not sort after being executed in case statements?

Comment: You should mark the best answer once 15 minutes has been passed, don't delete the question.

Comment: @his Not really - `return c2-c1` can fail with large negative numbers because of overflow... Hence my recommendation to use a built-in method to avoid that sort of hard to find error.

Comment: @assylias True, in case of overflow it doesn't work. Using the standard library function is the best solution in nearly any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget the `break`

```
switch ( x ) {
    case 0 :
        Collections.sort( p.members, new compareThings.CEmpathy());
        break; // IMPORTANT
   case 1 :
       Collections.sort( p.members, new compareThings.CFear());
       break; // IMPORTANT
   case 2 :
       Collections.sort( p.members, new compareThings.CCarry());
       break; // can be omitted here
}
```

because `switch` cases are fall through, in your code the last statement will always be `Collections.sort( p.members, new compareThings.CCarry());` as long as `x` is either 0, 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2):

Noted by jlordo comment and answer, the problem was the lack of usage of the `break` keyword at the end of each `case` of your `switch` statement. IMO you could move all this logic inside a `Map<Integer, Comparator< Creature >>` and have each key mapped with the corresponding comparator you want/need. I'll post a basic example:

```
//sorry couldn't think of a better name for your class :)
public class ClassThatSortCreatures {

    Map<Integer, Comparator<Creature>> mapComparators = new HashMap<Integer, Comparator<Creature>>();
    public ClassThatSortCreatures() {
        //initialize the map
        mapCoparators.put(0, new compareThings.CEmpathy());
        mapCoparators.put(1, new compareThings.CFear());
        mapCoparators.put(2, new compareThings.CCarry());
    }

    public void SortCreatures ( int x ) {
        for ( Party p : SorcerersCave.theCave.parties ) {
            //avoiding usage of switch
            Collections.sort( p.members, mapCoparators.get(x));
        }
        generateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "Displaying Sorted Creatures:" );
        for ( Party p : SorcerersCave.theCave.parties ) {
            generateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "" + p );
            for ( Creature c : p.members ){
                generateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "\t" + c );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And your code looks even cleaner and easier to maintain. Another tip to enhance this approach would be that instead of using an `int` parameter you could use an `enum` to avoid validating if the `Comparator` exists in the map.

Comment: Or, after converting the int to an enum, just make the comparator accessible through the enum.

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement needs to be changed from

```
switch ( x ) {
    case 0 :
        Collections.sort( p.members, new compareThings.CEmpathy());
    case 1 :
        Collections.sort( p.members, new compareThings.CFear() );
    case 2 :
        Collections.sort( p.members, new compareThings.CCarry() );
}
```

to

```
switch ( x ) {
    case 0 :
        Collections.sort( p.members, new compareThings.CEmpathy());
        break;
    case 1 :
        Collections.sort( p.members, new compareThings.CFear() );
        break;
    case 2 :
        Collections.sort( p.members, new compareThings.CCarry() );
        break;
}
```

Without the break statements, every line underneath the correct one will be executed as well. So if x was 2, everything would be sorted using CCarry(). If x was 1, everything would be sorted with CFear() and then CCarry(). If x is 0, the data is sorted by all three.